# Docker hub automated build fails but locally does not

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have setup an automated build on Docker hub [here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mbrt/golang-vim-dev/) (the sources are [here](https://github.com/michele-bertasi/go-docker-dev)).

The build goes well locally. I have also tried to rebuild it with `--no-cache` option:

```
docker build --no-cache .
```

And the process completes successfully

```
Successfully built 68b34a5f493a
```

However, the automated build fails on Docker hub with this error log:

```
...
Cloning into 'nerdtree'...
[91mVim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
[0m
[91mVim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
[0m
[m[m[0m[H[2J[24;1HError detected while processing command line:
E492: Not an editor command: PluginInstall
E492: Not an editor command: GoInstallBinaries
[91mmv: cannot stat `/go/bin/*': No such file or directory
[0m
```

This build apparently fails on the following vim command:

```
vim +PluginInstall +GoInstallBinaries +qall
```

Note that the warnings `Output is not to a terminal` and `Input is not to a terminal` appears also in the local build.

I cannot understand how this can happen. I am using a standard Ubuntu 14.04 system.

Comment: Seems to me that you have figured it out.

Comment: @Cyborg You are right. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The issue was related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28649793/1667955).

I am using Docker 1.0 in my host machine, however a later version is in production in Docker Hub. Without the explicit `ENV HOME=...` line in the Dockerfile, version 1.0 uses `/` as home directory, while `/root` is used by the later version. The result is that `vim` was not able to find its `.vimrc` file, since it was copied in `/` instead of `/root`. The solution I used is to explicitly define `ENV HOME=/root` in my Dockerfile, so there are no differences between the two versions.