# Different home directory during Docker build in Docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have found a strange difference between building docker images in my Ubuntu 14.04 host machine and the Docker Hub automated builds.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:wheezy-scm
RUN echo $HOME
```

This is the output in my machine:

```
 ---> 2afbec25f6f6
Step 1 : RUN echo $HOME
 ---> Running in 6074455e13c0
/
 ---> 0cb1b6141f93
Removing intermediate container 6074455e13c0
Successfully built 0cb1b6141f93
```

And this one comes from Docker hub:

```
---> 2afbec25f6f6
Step 1 : RUN echo $HOME
/root
---> 4c781d2d7d72
Successfully built 4c781d2d7d72
```

Note the different `HOME` directories: `/root` instead of `/`. Can anyone explain me what is happening?

This is my Docker version (I have installed the standard`docker.io` Ubuntu package):

```
$ docker version
Client version: 1.0.1
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 990021a
Server version: 1.0.1
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 990021a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively there were a change in `$HOME`, and the changes were merged after Docker release `v1.0`. I have built the Dockerfile you provided and it shows me `$HOME=/root` (I use Docker `v1.5.0`). Check [Docker Issue #2968](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2968) and related commits for additional details.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. I have added `ENV HOME /root` at the beginning of my Dockerfile. In this way the behavior is the same for both versions.